# tweepy get list of failed lookup_users

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'd like to check if a set of twitter users are exist or not. As I couldn't find any better method, I used `api.lookup_users()` but it returns nothing when a user name is not found. How can I get list of users that are failed to look up.

```
>>> api = tweepy.API(auth)
>>> user_ids = api.lookup_users(screen_names['hamid', 'python'])
>>> print user_ids
[19877641]
```

But I need the failed ones also something like: `[19877641,None]` or `[19877641,""]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more on Twitter's side than tweepy. If a user is not found using [`GET users/lookup`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup) nothing is returned. So tweepy is returning what is being received from the API.

From their docs:

> There are a few things to note when using this method.
>
> - You must be following a protected user to be able to see their most    recent status update. If you don’t follow a protected user their
>     status will be removed.
> - The order of user IDs or screen names may not match the order of    users in the returned array.
> - **If a requested user is unknown, suspended, or deleted, then that user will not be returned in the results list.**
> - If none of your lookup criteria can be satisfied by returning a user object, a HTTP 404 will be thrown.
> - You are strongly encouraged to use a POST for larger requests.

A possible workaround is to send the users individually and if you get `None` then change your list accordingly. Unfortunately that can hinder you limit.

Comment: Yes I have to send one user at the time. But it is really bad decision to left no trace when requested user is not there, only one wrong user among hundred can mess everything up. Thanks.